# Is There a Way to Force Intellisense to Re-evaluate Available Overloads?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

Visual Studio is having problems evaluating potential overloads for a massive ASP.NET CMS application that I'm working on.  There are lots of cases where intellisense incorrectly thinks that there are no available overloads for methods that should have them.  I am wondering if there is a way to force Visual Studio Intellisense to re-evaluate the method for possible overloads.

I have already cleared the application cache in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files and I am running into this problem with solutions that I've never opened before.  I am working on multiple versions of this application on different machines, but I've also had this issue on a server with Visual Studio installed that I'm just now using for the first time.  This leads me to believe that clearing my individual user temp files would do nothing.

```
//in my viewmodel:

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        int CourseID = 50;
        string type = Utils.GetCertificateType(CourseID);

        string lblUserName1;

        lblUserName1 = Utils.GetUserFullName(CourseID.ToString());

}

//and in Utils.cs

public static string GetUserFullName(string CourseID)
{
    string UserID = GetCurrentUserID(CourseID);
    QueryDataParameters parameters = new QueryDataParameters();
    parameters.Add("@UserID", UserID);

    DataSet rdr = ConnectionHelper.ExecuteQuery("UserFullName", parameters, QueryTypeEnum.StoredProcedure);

    var FullName = ValidationHelper.GetString(rdr.Tables[0].Rows[0]["FullName"], String.Empty);

    return FullName;
}
```

I'm getting an error from Intellisense claiming GetUserFullName doesn't take one argument. "No overload for method 'GetUserFullName' takes 1 arguments" As you can see from the code example, it definitely *does* take one argument.  It's really hard to search for this type of issue because most of the examples will be where someone isn't inputting the correct parameter type, but I know in this case it's correct.

ASP.NET web applications are new to me; I know that when Xamarin used to do stuff like this sometimes I would have to delete everything from .vs bin and obj folders.  I don't see a .vs folder but I do have obj and bin.  This project would take a very very long time to build.  Would it help if I delete everything out of those folders and do a rebuild?

I've noticed this type of thing has been happening a lot in this massive solution.  The compiler won't recognize certain methods or overloads, even though they're clearly defined in their respective classes.  Any advice would help me out a lot.